# Javascript string to int array

Tags: javascript, integer, flawed-concept

```
var result ="1fg";
for(i =0; i < result.length; i++){
  var chr = result.charAt(i);
  var hexval = chr.charCodeAt(chr)
  document.write(hexval + " ");
}
```

This gives NaN 102 103.

Probably because it's treating the "1" as a integer or something like that. Is there a way I can convert the 
"1"->string to the correct integer? In this case: 49.

So it will be

49 102 103 instead of NaN 102 103

Cheers,

Timo

Comment: 1. Did you declare `i`? 2. Don't put declarations inside loops. It's best to declare all variables beforehand. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yJVSA/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `charCodeAt` function takes an index, not a string.

When you pass it a string, it will try to convert the string to a number, and use `0` if it couldn't.

Your first iteration calls `'1'.charCodeAt('1')`.  It will parse `'1'` as a number and try to get the second character code in the string.  Since the string only has one character, that's `NaN`.

Your second iteration calls `'f'.charCodeAt('f')`.  Since `'f'` cannot be parsed as a number, it will be interpreted as `0`, which will give you the first character code.

---

You should write `var hexval = result.charCodeAt(i)` to get the character code at the given position in the original string.

You can also write `var hexval = chr.charCodeAt(0)` to get the character code of the single character in the `chr` string.

Comment: THANKS!! How could I have looked over that! I can't believe it, I've been looking at this code for hours now ^^ I'd give you 100 upvotes if I could

Comment: Thanks for the explaination too. It really makes sense now!